# Jenkins Pipeline with dynamic parameters

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I have a Jenkins running in with multiple agents on windows. I want a Pipeline with a dynamic parameters which should be populated with a list of folders on the windows agent. I got following code:

```
def listSDKVersions() {
    return{
        agent { label 'windows' }
        stage {
            bat "dir Z:\\ /b"
        }
    }
}

def SDKVersions = listSDKVersions()

pipeline {
    agent { label 'windows && docker' }
    parameters {
        choice(name: 'SDK', choices: SDKVersions , description: 'SDK Version')
    }
}
```

but when I execute it I get the following Error:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: expected String or List, but got org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsClosure2
    at hudson.model.ChoiceParameterDefinition.setChoices(ChoiceParameterDefinition.java:105)
```

Does someone know how to do this properly or is it even possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it running like that:

```
def listSDKVersions() {
    return{
        node('windows'){
            def folders = bat(script:"@dir Z:\\ /b", returnStdout:true)
            return folders
        }
    }
}

def SDKVersions = listSDKVersions().call()

pipeline {
    agent { label 'windows && docker' }
    parameters {
        choice(name: 'SDK', choices: SDKVersions , description: 'SDK Version')
    }
}
```